# JS funciona no Greasemonkey, mas não funciona diretamnete na página

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, tampermonkey

Estou fazendo alguns testes utilizando o Google ReCaptcha.

O que estou tentando fazer é clicar automaticamente no checkbox quando o captcha aparecer. Peguei essa função `teste()` no site do `greasemonkey` e ela funciona perfeitamente utilizando o plugin, porém ela não funciona se a adiciono diretamente na minha página.

Alguém saberia me dizer o por quê disso? O que o `greasemonkey` faz de diferente para o *script* funcionar?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body onload='test();'>
        <form action="hello" method="POST">
            <div id='testid'>
                <div class="g-recaptcha"
                    data-sitekey="SITE_KEY_HERE"
                    data-callback="onSuccess">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>

        function test() {
            var domain = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer.toString() : document.location.toString();
            if (domain.indexOf('miped.ru') == -1 && domain.indexOf('indiegala') == -1 && domain.indexOf('gleam.io') == -1) {
                var clickCheck = setInterval(function() {
                    console.log('test');
                    if (document.querySelectorAll('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark').length > 0) {
                        clearInterval(clickCheck);
                        document.querySelector('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark').click();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        }

        var onSuccess = function(response) {
              alert(grecaptcha.getResponse());
        };

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferença é que quando você adiciona o ReCaptcha através do código abaixo, o script da Google cria, automaticamente um `iframe`.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY-KEY"></div>
```

Acontece que quando você tenta alterar um elementro dentro desse `iframe`, você não consegue. Isso é devido a segurança.

Já o `greasemonkey` injeta esse mesmo `script` dentro do `iframe` criado, por isso funciona corretamente.

Inclusive você pode testar isso *(Irei usar o Chrome para o teste)*.

**Passo 1** - Acesse https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

**Passo 2** - Pressione `F12` para abrir o console do navegador.

**Passo 3** - Informe o código `document.querySelector('iframe').querySelector('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark');` e pressione enter.

> Veja que nada acontece. Isso porque você está tentando acessar um elementro de um iframe fora dele.

**Passo 4** - Agora altere o acesso para dentro do iframe da Google. Clique em `Top` e posteriormente em `Anchor`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 5** - Agora que você "está dentro" do iframe criado, você pode acessar e modificar quaisquer elemento dentro dele. Experimente executando o código abaixo.

```
document.querySelector('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark').click();
```

É dessa forma que o `greasemonkey` faz. Ele simplesmente injeta o código dentro o iframe, possibilitando que ele acesse/modifique determinado evento de um elemento.

Comment: Hmm, interessante. E como ele consegue injetar se os domínios são diferentes?

Comment: Quais domínios? Se possível passa o link do post original do `greasemonkey`.

Comment: Não, digo, o domínio do iframe é do Google. Não é possível alterar um iframe sendo que ele possui outro domínio do que meu site correto?

O post original do greasemonkey é esse: https://greasyfork.org/pt-BR/scripts/18449-recaptcha-helper/code

Comment: Quando o navegador faz a requisição para o script o `greasemonkey` detecta o retorno e usa o próprio navegador para injetar esse código. Quando você tenta alterar o iframe em sua página html, é o navegador que bloqueia essa ação. Você também pode fazer essas inserções com o uso de [Extensões para o Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) ou [WebExtensions para o Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: Ahh, então não tem jeito de eu fazer o mesmo, injetar esse script, pela minha página?

Comment: Não. Não tem jeito. Somente com uso de extensões para os navegadores.

Comment: Que saco ^^
Mas obrigado, foi muito esclarecedor!